# How to embed/spawn an interactive shell from inside a Python program

Tags: python, shell, terminal, command-line-interface

I have a Python 3 CLI application from which I want to drop into or spawn an interactive bash shell (after I’ve set some custom environment vars).

What is the best way to embed or spawn an interactive bash shell in Python?

#### More details

The whole procedure can be described in the following 6 steps:

1. The user starts my CLI application in a Terminal session. (It should work regardless whether the app runs in *iTerm* or *Xterm* or the like, but the underlying system is Unix-ish.)
2. Then the application gathers some information from the user via prompts (so the application uses stdin and stdout).
3. Then it should spawn a bash shell prompt. This bash is suppose to:

   - run *in the same terminal session* as my app and
   - use an environment with some custom environment vars set by my application beforehand.
4. The user executes some commands in the bash shell (using the same stdin and stout from my app before).
5. The user exists the bash shell via Ctrl-d or `exit`.
6. The bash shell closes and my Python app takes over again *in the same terminal session*. It does some post [proecssing and the  finishes.

**The part I am asking about is step 3 (Spawn the bash shell).**

#### What I've tried to spawn a bash

1. I tried using the [code module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) in the Standard Library, but this only allows me to start a *Python* shell not a *bash* shell.
2. I used the [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh) package:

   ```
    from sh import bash
    bash('-i')
   ```

   This doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you need from the Bash session, other than it being interactive? Do you want access to e.g. the standard output generated by Bash from within Python?

Comment: @halloleo: What do you mean by _dropping an application into an interactive shell_?

Comment: @jmd_dk Well, eventually I would like to get a list of all the commands the user executed in the Bash session. But that is another issue I have already ideas how to tackle,

Comment: @user1934428 I explained the whole thing in more deatil in the question. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['bash', '-li'])
```

You can pass your custom environment via `env` function parameter, and anything more with `--rcfile` bash argument.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem:

```
import os
os.system("x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/bash")
```

Comment: Sorry, that I was not clear enough in my first description. I explained the whole thing in more detail in the question. So I _cannot_ launch another terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

To get an upgraded shell

```py
python3 -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("/bin/bash")'
```